# Selection of DC Motor Drivers

Tags: motor

Is there different Motor Drivers available for Permanent Magnet DC Motor and Wound Rotor DC Motor .Specifically for Series and Parallel wound DC Motor .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A brushless Permanent magnet DC motor requires a controller that switches the polarity of the voltage applied to the windings similarly to supplying AC to the windings.

A DC motor with a commutator (and wound rotor) requires variable-voltage DC applied to the armature. The field is usually supplied by a separate fixed or variable-voltage DC supply rather than being series or parallel connected. The field can also be a permanent magnet with the same type of controller less the separate power supply for the field.

If you search PMDC motor control and armature voltage DC motor control you should be able to find detailed explanations of each type. There are a lot of details and variations to the designs, a lot of features, and a lot of aspects of the their of operation. There is much more than can be covered in this question and answer format.

Comment: Sir , I have learnt that Speed and Torque of a DC Motor can be controlled by two ways one varying the Armature supply and the second by varying the Field Supply , Why do we generally prefer to vary Armature Supply rather than Field Supply .

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A series wound commutator motor is know as universal motor. You can find it in many domestic appliances. The electronic speed control is usualy made with AC voltage and phase angle control with SCR or triacs.

A shunt wound motor (parallel) usually doesn't have any electronic control as  the purpose of its use, is the characteristics to self-regulate the motor speed.

A separate excited motor, is basicaly the same as the PMDC. Instead of magnets there is a field winding. If the winding is fed with constant DC voltage, then the excitation current is almost constant. Any electronic driver for PMDC will work also for DC motor with separate excitation.